# How to properly Disconnect and Reconnect the Chrome Runtime Port to a Native Host?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Following on from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606341/when-should-i-start-a-native-message-host-when-targeting-both-google-chrome-and) I am now connecting and disconnecting the port to my native host based on when a user opens or closes a website tab.  I do not know how to reconnect the port.

Originally when I only opened the port once I had;

```
if (typeof port !== 'undefined') return;
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('name_to_host');
```

Now I have added `port.disconnect();` when the user closes a certain tab or navigates away from the website.

This port is then still an object but is in a disconnected state.

What am I supposed to do with it now? Can I somehow "dispose" the port object or can I reconnect somehow?

Comment: Thanks but I have that in my question already. What then? How do I reconnect?

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I don't understand the question. Usually there's no need to dispose of anything in JavaScript.

Comment: There's no such thing as "reconnect" either. Simply call connectNative again and assign it to the same variable or to another one, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Ok great. So the port object has no state property? You either try to send a message and get an error or need to keep track through you code when it is disconnected, for example by listening to onDisconnect

Comment: Yep, do that as [there's no state](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question probably shows my lack of knowledge of Javascript, however for anyone landing here from Google here is what I am doing.

Backgound: I am opening and closing my port to a native messaging host based on a website. Simply put the host is not always running, therefore I am opening and closing the post.

In my code to open the port and thus start the host I still have

```
if (typeof port !== 'undefined') return;
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('name_to_host');
```

Where I have code sending a message I have the following;

```
if (typeof port !== 'undefined') port.postMessage({...});
```

When I want to disconnect the port and thus close the host I have

```
port.disconnect();
port = undefined;
```

I realize some may not agree with `port = undefined;` but this fits with my existing code and seems to work ok.